# Make image fit the height of responsively sized td

Tags: html, css

When using a div instead of a td, this works great:

```
<div style='height:50%;width:50%;'>
     <img style='height: inherit;' src='https://placehold.it/200x1000'>
</div>
```

But applying the same to a td doesn't work, instead it expands the td to the size of the image source:

```
<table style='height:50%;width:50%;'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img style='height: inherit;' src='https://placehold.it/200x1000'>
      </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: tables expand to fill their content by default there isn't any good way to force it. You are better off to use div's

Comment: using divs in my situation is going to be a nightmare  - is there no workaround..?

Comment: can I not wrap the image in a div somehow?

Comment: yup thats a good idea if to really do need to use a table then wrap the img tag in a div and set the width and height there.